# IntelliJ IDE And Font Misbehavior In Parameters

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, editor, preferences

Why is the font display in the IntelliJ editor not respecting my preferences? As you can see in the screenshot, "processEngineConfiguration" is not appearing in Fira Code font although I set it in Preferences > Editor > Font.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [an open issue for that](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-215293).

The comment from the responsible developer states:

> That's exactly the reason why hints are not rendered in monospaced font - to make it clear it's not the source code.

The issue is open, so you can vote for it and hope that there will be an option added to change the font of the parameter hints in the future IDE updates.